Hypothesis testing of Precision-Recall curve AUCs
In recent times, I have been about learning classification models (e.g., logistic regression) and how to evaluate them. While learning about the Precision-Recall (PR) curves, it occurred to me that information regarding the testing of the Area Under Curve (AUC) for the PR curve (i.e., PR-AUC) is rather scarce.
Particularly, it is unclear to me how one can conduct hypothesis testing for 2 or more PR-AUCs. As such, I seek your guidance as to the following:

how can one compare two PR-AUCs to say that there is a statistically significant difference between them? (i.e., like the DeLong method available in R's pROC::roc.test())
How can one compare multiple PR-AUCs together to say that there is a statistically significant difference between them? (i.e., any holistic tests like F-tests for means, or generalised U-statistic for ROC-AUC according to ChatGPT-4o [citation needed])

I understand that it is possible to utilise bootstrapping somehow. However, I also note that it is not appropriate for smaller sample sizes, which is what I am mainly working with. I am looking more for a mathematical approach. So, do bear that in mind in your replies.
